# Powershell move lines around in a file

Tags: powershell, line, move

This seems so simple I'm embarrassed to ask.

I have a file with an unknown number of lines but at least 20.  I always want to move lines 4-6 to lines 1-3.

So this:

```
A

B

C

D

E

F

G

H
```

becomes this:

```
D

E

F

A

B

C

G

H
```

Original attempt which does not work.

```
$path = "C:\xxxx"
$pathnew = $path + "\new"
If(!(test-path $pathnew))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $pathnew
}


[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Files = @(Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.json |
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | 
    Select-Object FullName,Name)

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$File_Contents = @(Get-Content $File.FullName)

    $FN = $File.FullName 
    $OutPutFile = $pathnew + "\" + $File.Name 

    $txt = Get-Content $FN
    $txt2 = Get-Content $FN | Measure-Object -Line 
    $txtLess3 = $txt2.Lines-3
    $txt[6..12],"`"submission`": {",$txt[1..3]
    ,"  `"performanceYear`": 2019},"
    ,$txt[13..$txtLess3] | Out-File $OutPutFile 
}
```

This does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Lines = 'A'..'H'
$Lines[3..5],$Lines[0..2],$Lines[6..99]
```

or

```
$Lines[3,4,5,0,1,2,6,7,8,9]
```

For details, see: [about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7)

Comment: thank you.  that just replaced about 20 lines of my ignorant code.